# Need some help getting started in Counterstrike: Global Offensive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm new to CS:GO and I need a little help on some stuff:

1. How do I acquire guns/cases/crates/etc?
2. How do I start a match with a gun of my own instead of a preset one?
3. Once I have a case do I need to purchase a key to open it, if so how?

P.S. I am on mac and I dont know if that will affect any of the answers to these questions.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade! While the users on here are generally good at recieving "newbie questions" it is a bit hard for us to answer the questions along the lines of "I am new, what should I do". My recommendation would be to look around the CS wikia, look up a few game guides or join the official forums for advice on how to play. If you have a more specific question, you are welcome to post. Perhaps your three main points could be better worded as individual questions?

Comment: In addition to that you should split your questions to several threads. This will prevent that e.g. two questions are getting discussed here and you will lose clear view. Anyhow, welcome!

Answer (score 9):

> 1.How do I acquire guns/cases/crates/etc?

You can either buy them, or you just receive them randomly at the end of a round, after playing a round you may notice a couple of players receive something in the end score screen. Keep playing and you'll get a few things.

The only gun skins you can get at the end of a round are very common ones. To get rarer ones you'll need to open cases (see 3.), win them on sites like csgolounge.com or purchase them from the market.

> 2.How do I start a match with a gun of my own instead of a preset one?

Go to inventory and for each gun skin you want, click it and select replace ct/t/both. When you start a game then you'll have the appropriate skin on the weapons. You can also access the inventory from in game, escape>inventory, however, you can't access it while alive nor while playing competitively.

> 3.Once I have a case do I need to purchase a key to open it, if so how?

Yes, you need to purchase keys in order to open crates. You can buy keys from both the community market (Steam) or the in game market. Once you get a case it's very easy to follow the links in order to purchase keys to open it.

Comment: @Luke I'm glad to hear that it helped! Remember to mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question, or you can ask for a bit more information on certain points if you wish.